# How to manually set errors for min length?

Tags: angular

I'm trying

control.setErrors({ minlength: true });

But how can you specify a min length of 4.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding how `setErrors` works. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to manually set errors, instead of letting my Reactive Form do it, I have a complex form that requires me to dynamically set and remove errors on dynamically generated controls.

Comment: The error only knows whether it failed the rule or not, it doesn't know what the parameters of the rule are.  If the control needs to know what the length is supposed to be, you'll have to pass that in a different way.

Comment: No, I have that already.. having issues with it thats why i'm resorting to this.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidationErrors - says key:any - so why not minlength:4 ?? - param for https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setErrors

Comment: Resolved my issue, I was not doing:
    this.answerControlArr[questionId - 1].setValidators(Validators.compose([ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]));


Instead I was declaring each separately like so:
       this.answerControlArr[questionId - 1].setValidators( Validators.required);
        this.answerControlArr[questionId - 1].setValidators( Validators.minLength(4));

Not realizing, It was overriding the first validator. Thank you guys very much.

Comment: I was gonna also say, maybe...  updateValueAndValidity(opts:{onlySelf :true})

Comment: @TaranjitKang - Hah.. Like the examples.. https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validation-directive